# Unable to install software on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, c++, gcc, g++, ubuntu-8.04

I have recently installed 8.04 Ubuntu onto an industrial board and applied the vendor kernel modifications to it. I need to develop applications on another desktop to run on this board in C++ but I am unable to install any software (specifically build-essential) on it so I am left with gcc 4.2.4 which is simply not an option as our application must be C++. I really do not know what to do here as this version is unsupported. I found this answer here [Installing software on an old Ubuntu version that's no longer supported (2009 Jaunty)](https://superuser.com/questions/301432/installing-software-on-an-old-ubuntu-version-thats-no-longer-supported-2009-ja) but unfortunately this does not help at all.

EDIT: The installation is made on a compact flash card attached to the board using USB CD-ROM drive. The vendor suggests that 9.04 and 10.04 are supported but using the ubuntu .iso installation images I have been unable to successfully install either of these successfully, hence I am stuck with 8.04.

Is there any way I can install what I want from a CD ?

Any help or suggestions would be very gratefully received as I am a software developer and not a system administrator and feeling a little out of my depth here.

Comment: Any reason why you can't upgrade to the latest version? Like development environment etc?

Comment: @jokerdino The installation is made onto a compact flash card that is acting as a hard drive on the board. Thus far using ubuntu installation discs 8.04 is the only version that installs successfully. Also according to the vendor the board only supports up to 10.04 version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a possibility, I suggest you download 10.04 ISO (I would actually recommend 12.04, but you claim hardware issues) and burn a CD, back up all the data and do a fresh install. It probably is the recommended way since 8.04 is long outdated.

If that is not a possibility, use this command

```
sudo sed -i 's/hardy/lucid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to upgrade to 10.04. I would assume that would work but I haven't really used 8.04. So, it might not be the one that you are looking for. Use it at your discretion.

The gcc version in 10.04 is 4.4.3. Might not be what you are looking for but better than being stuck in 8.04.

At any case, back up your data. There is more than a chance that things can go from bad to worse.

Comment: I tried the 10.04 ISO and installation failed, same with 9.04 and debian 5.0. Backup is not important - this is a fresh install to test the feasibility of developing on Linux. Previously my company used DOS and clearly I am keen to avoid having to learn obsolete tech. Will I then have to reapply the vendor kernel updates again? Sorry if I am asking facile questions here.

Comment: It looks more like a hardware issue than a software one. Give these commands a shot anyway. If it works, consider yourself lucky. If the vendor has kernel updates for 10.04, apply them. If not, then you probably are out of luck.

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Good luck with the adventure. :)